# Loading a couple images based on a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load images based on the value here (Using React and JavaScript).
Let me show you what I've currently got.

```
this.state.categories.map((value, index) => {
     return <div className={categoryStyle.column}
                 key={index}
                 onClick={() => {this.setCategory(value)}}>
            <img src={this.getImage(value)}/>
     </div>
}) : <Spinner/> }
```

```
getImage = (category) => {
    switch(category) {
        case "people":
            return "./img/people.png"
        case "planets":
            return "./img/planets.png"
        case "films":
            return "./img/films.png"
        case "species":
            return "./img/species.png"
        case "vehicles":
            return "./img/vehicles.png"
        case "starships":
            return "./img/starships.png"
        default:
            return console.log("No image available")
    }
}
```

The value contains the category names, such as people or films.
When I check in my Html the image src actually shows the /img/people.png, but the image is not loading.

What am I doing wrong here? Also, is there a more recommended way of doing this more dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue here was that my images were in the src/img folder. I placed my images folder in the public folder now and everything works now!

I have also removed my function and just did the following.

`<img height="50" src={"./categoryImages/" + value + ".png"}/>`

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `require` inside `src` prop:

```
<img src={require(this.getImage(value))} />
```

However I would suggest you to replace your `switch` function with simple if else (require may not evaluate your `console.log` properly).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually had my images in the src folder. I have placed them in the public folder and now it's working! :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how I would handle the same thing but with background images? edit: never mind I already fixed it!